# what is css code to hide this div

Tags: html, css

what is the css code to hide this div

```
<div id="x_afc_x" class="section ">
```

I need to hide it because it is automatically added to my page.

Comment: this is a vendor-prefixed class... you are using some framework... normally you could hide the item in the framework itself. please have a look at css-visiblilty, if this is not the case

Comment: Check the following link for a tutorial: http://www.randomsnippets.com/2008/02/12/how-to-hide-and-show-your-div/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could hide it with

```
#x_afc_x { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Just define your** `#x_afc_x` `display:none;`

As like this

```
#x_afc_x{
display:none;
}
```

### ----------

Or section option is this

```
#x_afc_x.section{
display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
  <div id="x_afc_x" class="section " style="display:none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#x_afc_x

{
  display:none
}
```

or

```
#x_afc_x

{
   visibility:hidden;

}
```